# Simplify $e^{x \cdot \log{y}}$ where $x, y \in R^N$

Tags: exponential-function, vectors, exponentiation

I'm looking to simplify the following expression (or to determine if it's even possible). Given two vectors $x, y \in R^N$, simplify $e^{x \cdot \log{y}}$. I found it in some m-code for an infinite mixture model I've come across, and I'm trying to verify the model for correctness.

Comment: What are your own ideas about it? Where are you stuck? Show something of your own work! Is $\log ~\cdot~$ the logarithm to the base $e$?

Comment: What is $\log y$ if $y$ is a vector? Do you apply $\log$ to all components?

Comment: If the $y_i$ are all positive and the log is taken component wise, this is $\Pi_{i=1}^N y_i^{x_i}$. Otherwise it is undefined .